# How to focus ion-searchbar on button click

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I am trying to focus `ion-searchbar` on button click but it is not working. 
This is my code

**Typescript**

```
@ViewChild('search') search:ElementRef;

focusButton(){
       console.log(this.search);   //Searchbar {_config: Config, _elementRef: ElementRef, _renderer: RendererAdapter, _componentName: "searchbar", _mode: "md", …}
       console.log(this.search.nativeElement); //  null
       this.search.nativeElement.focus();      //  Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined
        this.search.nativeElement.setFocus();      // Cannot read property 'setFocus' of undefined

}
```

**Html**

```
<ion-searchbar #search (ionCancel)="cancelSearch($event)" [showCancelButton]="true" [(ngModel)]="artists"></ion-searchbar>
        <ion-buttons end>
            <button [hidden]="showSearch" (click)="(showSearch = !showSearch) && focusButton()" ion-button icon-only>
              <ion-icon  name="search"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-buttons>
```

The console output is above in comments with code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hope you can do it using below code.Just try it using `setTimeout` as shown below.

*.html*

```
<ion-searchbar #search (ionCancel)="cancelSearch($event)" 
[showCancelButton]="true" [(ngModel)]="artists"></ion-searchbar>

<ion-buttons end>
   <button [hidden]="showSearch" (click)="(showSearch = !showSearch) && focusButton()" ion-button icon-only>
    <ion-icon  name="search"></ion-icon>
  </button>
</ion-buttons>
```

*.ts*

```
@ViewChild('search') search : any;

focusButton(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.search.setFocus();
    }, 500);
  }
```

Comment: Hi mate, I am getting setFocus is not a function

Comment: Can you put a new question and let me know? @user1195369

Comment: The `500` timeout is crucial, well for iOS at least... less than that (tried with `50`) keyboard will slide in and then slide back out.. the `500` kinda gives time to prevent for any other trigger action interference.. hope this helps others..

Comment: sir it is working properly in case of the if our input is show but not working if our input is hide.like we have click the search icon and input field is show here now seach will be undefined how to image this case sir?

Answer (score 6):

For those working with **Angular 8** and Ionic 4 one can set the flag `static: false` which will consider that an `*ngIf` is involved and hiding the search bar for example. As soon `*ngIf` displays again the visual component (e.g. `ion-searchbar`)

```
@ViewChild('searchInput', {static: false}) searchInput: IonSearchbar;

  constructor() { }

  public setSearchbarVisible(isVisible) {
    this.isSearchbarOpened = isVisible;
    if (isVisible) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.searchInput.setFocus();
    }, 100);
    }
  }
```

Adding a type to the `searchInput` will also help with method and property insights, like `setFocus()`. That is neat code without daring to touch the wraped native elements.

Comment: how is `setSearchbarVisible` being invoked? do we have to do it manually or is it called by ionic?

Answer (score 6):

1-) **Import IonSearchBar Element**

```
import { IonSearchbar} from '@ionic/angular';
```

2-) **Create ViewChild for IonSearchBar**

```
@ViewChild(IonSearchbar) myInput: IonSearchbar;
```

3-) **Set focus with timeout**

```
setTimeout(() => { this.myInput.setFocus(); }, 150);
```

--

Open Request feature here:
[ion-searchbar autofocus #17745](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/17745)

Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add reference into the template

   `<input #inputEl>`
   or `<ion-searchbar #inputEl>` whatever you use as *input*
2. Import `ViewChild` on the top of *.ts* and define a reference variable in component *class*

   ```
   import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
   @ViewChild('inputEl') inputElRef;
   ```
3. Use `nativeElement` to access `focus()` function

   `this.inputElRef.nativeElement.focus();`

Comment: Just to note if using `<ion-searchbar>` then use as `this.inputElRef.nativeElement.querySelector('input').focus();`

Comment: yes, thanks @SavageCore.
should be used with every component which is having input as a child into the same