# How to get nativeElement from @ViewChild in Ionic 4/Angular7?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular7

I am using Ionic 4's ion-search like so:

```
     <ion-searchbar
            #searchbarElem
            (ionInput)="getItems($event)"
            (tap)="handleTap($event)"
            [(ngModel)]="keyword"
            (ngModelChange)="updateModel()"
            [cancelButtonText]="options.cancelButtonText == null ? defaultOpts.cancelButtonText : options.cancelButtonText"
            [showCancelButton]="options.showCancelButton == null ? defaultOpts.showCancelButton : options.showCancelButton"
            [debounce]="options.debounce == null ? defaultOpts.debounce : options.debounce"
            [placeholder]="options.placeholder == null ? defaultOpts.placeholder : options.placeholder"
            [autocomplete]="options.autocomplete == null ? defaultOpts.autocomplete : options.autocomplete"
            [autocorrect]="options.autocorrect == null ? defaultOpts.autocorrect : options.autocorrect"
            [spellcheck]="options.spellcheck == null ? defaultOpts.spellcheck : options.spellcheck"
            [type]="options.type == null ? defaultOpts.type : options.type"
            [disabled]="disabled"
            [ngClass]="{'hidden': useIonInput}"
            (ionClear)="clearValue(true)"
            (ionFocus)="onFocus()"
            (ionBlur)="onBlur()"
    >
    </ion-searchbar>
```

On click I run the following from within the component:

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
private documentClickHandler(event) {
    if ((this.searchbarElem
            && !this.searchbarElem._elementRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target))
        ||
        (!this.inputElem && this.inputElem._elementRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target))
    ) {
        this.hideItemList();
    }
}
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
```

I have tried setting timeouts and declaring searchbarElem as `ElementRef` with no luck.

I know this worked in Angular 2/Ionic 2 but now it is not. Did something change or is the shadow dom affecting thing? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: How are you accessing `searchbarElem` in ts ? Share the code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should use `ViewChild` with the `read: ElementRef` metadata property:

```
@ViewChild("searchbarElem", { read: ElementRef }) private searchbarElem: ElementRef;
```

and access the HTMLElement with `this.searchbarElem.nativeElement`:

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
private documentClickHandler(event) {
    console.log(this.searchbarElem.nativeElement);
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic3-search-bar-sample-xb2cq2) for a demo (see the code in the Home page).

Answer (score 9):

For those working with **Angular 8** and Ionic 4 one can set the flag `static: false` without attacking the native elements.

```
@ViewChild('searchInput', {static: false}) searchInput: IonSearchbar;
```

See this Stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45786205/how-to-focus-ion-searchbar-on-button-click/58531873#58531873):

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed the native HTML input element that is a child of the ion-input to use for Google Maps autocomplete that expects a native input element.

Resolving the getInputElement() returns this from a promise

```
<ion-input #searchBox type="text"></ion-input>
```

...

```
@ViewChild('searchBox', {static: true}) searchElementRef: any;
```

....

```
this.searchElementRef.getInputElement().then(nativeChildElement => { 
  // do something with native HTML element here ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ViewChild('inputSearch', { static: false }) inputSearch: IonSearchbar;

setTimeout(() => {
  this.inputSearch.getInputElement().then((el: HTMLInputElement) => {
    el.blur();
  });
}, 150);
```